# Species of Machin’s formula?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, trigonometry, inequality

I read the following problem:
$$A=6\arctan(\frac 18)+2\arctan(\frac{1}{57})+\arctan (\frac{1}{239})$$
$$B=24\arctan(\frac{1}{12943})-12\arctan(\frac{1}{682})+44\arctan((\frac{1}{57})+7\arctan(\frac{1}{239})$$
**Is it $A\lt B, A=B$ or $A>B?$**

I recognize the "adding up" $\arctan (\frac{1}{239})$ of the famed Machin’s formula $\frac{\pi}{4}=4\arctan (\frac 15)-\arctan(\frac{1}{239})$ and  an empirical calculation gives me an approximation  $A\approx B\approx \frac{\pi}{4}$ so very probably we have $A=B=\frac{\pi}{4}$ How to prove this last assertion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ A = \arg\left[(8+i)^6 (57+i)^2 (239+i)\right]=\arg\left(N+Ni\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
where $N=150837781250$. In a similar way you may compute $B$, too, and check that $B=A$.

Comment: What a mysterious $N$! Best regards.